# Is there a way to do App version management without App Stores?

Tags: react-native, version-control, app-store, apk, ipa

I’d like to find out if there is a way to do App version management without the app being hosted on any App Store(Play store or Apple Store)?

For example, user A, B and C are running an old version of the App (IPA and APK which was downloaded via a direct download link, e.g, app.com/version1.apk).

A new version of the app has been released with new features to app.com/version2.apk

Is there a way to prevent having all the users download and install the new APK manually?
E.g Through some form of version management system that keeps track of the Apps changes and does this automatically for them?

The purpose of this question is to  determine if there is a version management system that replicates what Google and Apple store does by serving updates to users when there is one, Without using Google and Apple store as a point of download. E.g. the app was downloaded from a different platform (a website), but has either integrated into it a version management system that doesn’t involve the user having to manually download the app again (and going through the process of deleting the old one and installing the new one over and over again when a new version comes out).

Comment: Assuming you're pushing javascript changes and not native code, you can use something like CodePush: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/distribution/codepush/

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thank you halfer will do. @jnpdx I’ll check it out now!